# Unable to push changes to my repository (Permission denied. The requested URL returned error: 403)

Tags: git, error-handling, token

I am attempting to push changes to a GitHub repo (that I have access to). Upon doing the usual:

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push origin master
```

I receive an input for username and password (I tried both my token and my GitHub login password), and, in both cases, received the error:

```
remote: Permission to uName/repo.git denied to uName.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/uName/repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

This is when my `.git/config` file contains the `https://` format:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "upstream"]
    url = https://github.com/uName/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/uName/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

When I update my `.git/config` file to contain the `ssh://git@` format:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "upstream"]
    url = ssh://git@github.com/uName/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@github.com/uName/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

and then I try to push again, I receive the error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I follow the advice to ensure I have the same public key on my GitHub account as in my `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file, as suggested in previous forums.

But the problem remains.

For now, I keep my `.git/config` file to be in the `https://` format.

I have followed numerous solutions on forums for two days now, but am still unable to resolve the issue.

As far as I can see, I have deleted any "github.com" keys/passwords on my KeyChain Access App (on my Mac), as was suggested and solved the problem for many folks in previous forums.

The command `git remote -v` gives me the following:

```
origin  https://github.com/uName/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/uName/repo.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/uName/repo.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/uName/repo.git (push)
```

I'm a bit stumped. I am hoping someone here could point me to advice on a (probably less-common) reason why I'm unable to push changes.

Thank you.

Comment: What should one do in my situation when there is no response? Is there another forum one might consider in my situation? Thank you.